# Perform a scan operation in a group of records in Pyspark Dataframe (Spark v1.6)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Experts, i have a requirement where in a group of records i need to perform "scan & Act" operation on a Pyspark dataframe. Here is my pyspark dataframe (Spark version 1.6) with 2 fields-

```
col1     effective_date
A        2019-02-01
A        2019-02-03
A        2019-02-05
A        2019-02-07
```

The desired outcome is-

```
col1     effective_date expiry_date
A        2019-02-01     2019-02-02
A        2019-02-03     2019-02-04
A        2019-02-05     2019-02-06
A        2019-02-07     2999-12-31
```

This is a typical SCD2 (slowly changing Dimension) operation where my records should be sorted by effective_date (ascending) and for the "group of" col1 values, 
every record should have an expiry_date of next record's (effective_date-1) and the last record with maximum effective_date in the group should have an assumed expiry_date of "2999-12-31"
as it is the latest record and it doesn't have a future instance yet, however if something does appear in future, it should expire.
For example-

```
col1     effective_date expiry_date
A        2019-02-01     2019-02-02
A        2019-02-03     2019-02-04
A        2019-02-05     2019-02-06
A        2019-02-07     2019-02-08
A        2019-02-09     2999-12-31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is a Window Function

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy("col1").orderBy("effective_date")
df = df.withColumn("expiry_date", F.date_sub(F.lead("effective_date").over(w), 1))
```